# c# Enter value into datatable via different forms

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a c# project with 4+ forms (parent-child relationship). In Form01 I create a datatable with initial 'Rating' values in it assigned to variable 'Horse':

```
public Form01()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dgvMeetings.DataSource = GetMeetings();
            dtRatings = GetRating();
        }
```

dtRatings table is produced by an SQL call as follows:

```
public DataTable GetRating()
        {
            DataTable dtRating = new DataTable();
            string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbx"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT 
                                                          Course
                                                        , Race
                                                        , Cloth
                                                        , Horse
                                                        , Rating
                                                        , Odds
                                                        FROM[Smartform].[dbo].[Entries]
                                                        where Date = convert(date, getdate() - 1) 
                                                        order by 1, 2, 3", con))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    dtRating.Load(reader);
                }
            }
            return dtRating;
        }
```

In Form4, I want to be able to update the 'Rating' value in dtRating by entering a value into a text box. I have been attempting to do this via a textbox-keyup call as follows:

```
private void TbxForm01_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
            {
                string searchExpression = "Horse = " + Form03.Horse;
                MessageBox.Show(searchExpression);
                DataRow[] foundRows;
                foundRows = Form01.dtRatings.Select(searchExpression);
                MessageBox.Show(foundRows.ToString());

            }
        }
```

As you can see i have only just started. My plan was to use Form03.Horse to look up Horse on dtRatings and retrieve row number. Then use that to overwrite rating value with textbox value.

The 1st messagebox shows the correct 'Horse' name. However, I can't get the foundrows expression to work and correctly retrieve the row number from dtRatings.

Can anyone help with this and show me how to overwrite rating value in dtRatings with textbox entered value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume what you're trying to do is a have a form to enter a Horse #/Name, and try to lookup this horse from the DataTable. This will do that. However you're then left with the DataRow, you'll need a TextBox called txtRating, which contains a number such as 4.3 that you'll want to update from:

In Form03:

```
private void txtHorse_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // If we hit enter and we have a horse value in the text box, look it up
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && txtHorse.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dt in Form01.dtRating.Rows)
        {
            if (dt["Horse"].ToString() == txtHorse.Text)
            {
                // We found the horse
                MessageBox.Show(
                    $"Found horse {dt["Horse"]} (course={dt["Course"]} race={dt["Race"]} cloth={dt["Cloth"]} rating={dt["Rating"]} odds={dt["Odds"]}");

                // TODO: Do something with the data row
                dt["Rating"] = 5; // Possibly decimal.Parse(txtRating.Text); ?

                // Apply updates
                dt.AcceptChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer - not quite: i wanted to update the rating in dtRatings with the value entered in the text box. However, I think i can do it by editing your code as follows:

Comment: foreach (DataRow dt in Form01.dtRatings.Rows)
                {
                    if (dt["Horse"].ToString() == Form03.Horse)
                    {
                        dt["Rating"] = int.Parse(tbxForm01.Text); 
                        dt.AcceptChanges();
                    }
                }

Comment: The problem is that when i hit enter in the textbox (after entering and overwriting the current value) it doesn't seem to do anything?

Comment: have used your answer and managed to achieve what i wanted - many thanks